# How to count characters when pressing tab, space,delete and backspace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question may be a duplicate but I wasn't able to find a solution so far. Maybe the way I searched is wrong.

I need to count the total characters of `textarea` along with spaces using "space key" "tab key" "delete" or "backspace".

So far I have the below code but I don't know why it is not considering tab space in the count.

```html
<textarea id="myTextArae"></textarea>
```

```js
$("#myTextArae").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
    let start = this.selectionStart;
    let end = this.selectionEnd;
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.val().substring(0, start) + "\t" + $this.val().substring(end));
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
    var txt = $("#balanceCharacInTxtarea").val();
    if (txt != parseInt("0")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
  }
})

$("#myTextArea").on("paste", function (e) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    that.check(e, e1, 0);
  }, 100);
});

check(eventcode, e1, code) {
  if (code === 0) {
    this.calculate = this.characterCount(e, e1, default);
  } if (code === 1) {
    this.calculate = e1 ? e1.length : 0;
  }
}
var default = 175
```

Comment: Where is your count code?

Comment: @epascarello  sorry. i've update it pls check

Comment: Your code is incomplete... No one can reproduce what you actually have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something as easy as

```
 $("#yourtextarea").keyup(function() {
    var count = $("#yourtextarea").val().length;
 });
```

This will count spaces, tabs, newlines and other characters. 
It will trigger on paste as well.

**Example**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").html(0);

    //this is for counting the characters
    $("#message").keyup(function() {
        var txtlgt = $("#message").val().length;
        $("#test").html(txtlgt);
    });
    
    //This is for enabling tabs in the textarea
    $("#message").on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 9){ 
            let start = this.selectionStart;
            let end = this.selectionEnd;
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.val($this.val().substring(0, start) + "\t" + $this.val().substring(end));
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>

<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for jumping into this. this what i exactly. but the issue is, after hitting number of time on tab, character goes to next line as expected, but followed by that tab itself getting counted but space not added.

Comment: tab also not focusing on next line.

Comment: @Idiot_cheg Could you elaborate that a bit? I don't really understand the problem

Comment: tab indent is not working for new line if you keep on press tab. the counts getting increased but there no changes happening on new line until unless if press 'space bar or enter key'

Comment: @Idiot_cheg Maybe you want to force the textarea to prevent auto linebreaks? See [>this<](https://jsfiddle.net/kr49psm5/) example.

Comment: sorry for coming again. am trying to say the when tab reach EOL of textarea it should come to next line, i dont want to use css here. 
if  tabbing reach max width of textarea it should come on next line
help me

Comment: clearly, if tabbing reaching EOL(maximum width of textarea or right side border)the focus should automatically comes to next line. this is what i need. can u pls help me on this

Comment: @Idiot_cheg Okay I get what you mean. You will probably have to manually count the characters in the line and then insert a line break since the HTML attribute `wrap="hard"` doesn't recognize tabs. However I think it would be better asking this as separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162864/discussion-between-idiot-cheg-and-nulldev).